# Why does MonoTouch crash on this simple code?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I totally do NOT understand why MonoTouch is crashing on this code. Let me outline my steps to get to this point:

1. New Project
2. New > iPhone View with Controller (called `TestScreen`)
3. In Main.cs, added: `window.AddSubview(new TestScreen().View);`
4. Added button to the TestScreen UIView, and added an outlet called `testButton` on 'File's Owner' (which should be my TestScreen controller), and linked up the button to that outlet.

Then, I added the following code:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            this.testButton.SetTitle("Test", UIControlState.Normal); // this works!
            this.testButton.TouchUpInside += HandleTestButtonhandleTouchUpInside;
        }

        int i = 0;
        void HandleTestButtonhandleTouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i += 1;
            this.testButton.SetTitle("Testing " + i.ToString(), UIControlState.Normal); // this crashes!
        }
```

Question is: Why does the *this.testButton.SetTitle()* method cause a crash?

Here's the application output at time of crash:

Stacktrace:

> at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain
>   (int,string[],intptr,intptr)    at
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00038]
>   in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:26
>   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/plasma/Source/iphone/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:31   at
>   MyApp.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/username/Projects/MyApp/MyApp/Main.cs:14   at (wrapper
>   runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_void_object
>   (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)

Native stacktrace:

```
0   MyApp               0x000d1965 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 343
1   MyApp               0x0000ffb4 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 322
2   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9476845b _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   UIKit                               0x01c981b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
5   UIKit                               0x01c9a647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
6   UIKit                               0x01c991f4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
7   UIKit                               0x01c2e0d1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
8   UIKit                               0x01c0f37a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
9   UIKit                               0x01c14732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
10  GraphicsServices                    0x03edfa36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00e21064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
12  CoreFoundation                      0x00d816f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00d7e983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00d7e240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00d7e161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
16  GraphicsServices                    0x03ede268 GSEventRunModal + 217
17  GraphicsServices                    0x03ede32d GSEventRun + 115
18  UIKit                               0x01c1842e UIApplicationMain + 1160
19  ???                                 0x09a7714b 0x0 + 161968459
20  ???                                 0x09a76f1c 0x0 + 161967900
21  ???                                 0x09a7651c 0x0 + 161965340
22  ???                                 0x09a76374 0x0 + 161964916
23  ???                                 0x09a764c6 0x0 + 161965254
24  MyApp               0x0000fd6f mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1332
25  MyApp               0x001ee239 mono_runtime_invoke + 137
26  MyApp               0x001f0920 mono_runtime_exec_main + 669
27  MyApp               0x001efd0a mono_runtime_run_main + 843
28  MyApp               0x000a3c62 mono_jit_exec + 200
29  MyApp               0x002a25eb main + 3838
30  MyApp               0x000030c9 _start + 208
31  MyApp               0x00002ff8 start + 40
```

Debug info from gdb:

> /tmp/mono-gdb-commands.DGcT7h:1: Error in sourced command file: unable
>   to debug self
>
> ================================================================= Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal
>   error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries used by your
>   application.

Comment: is testscreen the default mainwindow.xib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error turned out to be in my Step 3.

My `new TestScreen()` was going out of scope and getting disposed for some reason. Assigned it to a variable and then passed in variable to AddSubview() and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{
              i += 1;
                          ((UIButton) sender).SetTitle("Testing " + i.ToString(), UIControlState.Normal);

            });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to cast the sender to a UIButton. I hope that helps.

```
void HandleTestButtonhandleTouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i += 1;
        ((UIButton) sender).SetTitle("Testing " + i.ToString(), UIControlState.Normal);
    }
```

Comment: He isn't using the sender at all in the example.
the question is why does it crash when calling it this way